# Is there any implementation of threshold BGN homomorphic encryption?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, threshold-cryptography

The BGN paper (Evaluating 2-DNF Formulas on Ciphertexts) used a threshold variant of BGN. I also want to use this cryptosystem, however, I cannot find any open-source implementation. Is there any such an implementation? If not, how could I implement it (the secret key can be easily shared, but I do not know how to decrypt a ciphertext by each share and then combine these shares to get the final plaintext)? Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because generic requests for libraries are off topic, please try "software recommendations" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two implementations, I haven't used any of them though.

- https://github.com/baonq-me/bgn
- https://github.com/nasimmaleki/Cryptography